# How to collate list items with the same first item onto a map

Tags: list, scala

I know this is probably a very simple List operation in Scala, but I'm a newbie and can't figure it out. I have a query that returns a result set with a series of values, grouped by a common id. For example:

Result Set:

```
[{ 1, "a", 30 },
{ 1, "b", 20 },
{ 1, "c", 22 },
{ 2, "a", 32 },
{ 2, "c", 10 }]
```

and what I'd like to do is put this into a map as such:

```
1 -> [{"a", 30}, {"b", 20}, {"c", 22}]
2 -> [{"a", 32}, {"c", 10}]
```

I think the collect method can be used for this but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure what the types in your data structure are, but maybe you can adapt this.  This assumes you have a collection of tuples:

```
val items = 
  List((1, "a", 30),
       (1, "b", 20),
       (1, "c", 22),
       (2, "a", 32),
       (2, "c", 10))

items
  .groupBy{ case (a,b,c) => a }
  .mapValues(_.map{ case (a,b,c) => (b,c) })

// Map(1 -> List((a,30), (b,20), (c,22)), 2 -> List((a,32), (c,10)))
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
items.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(t => (t._2, t._3)))
```

The `collect` method is something else entirely (basically, it's `map` that drops non-matching values).  The `groupBy` method is what you were really looking for.